# Groovy Script to find a string in console output and make the build failure

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have the following entry in the Jenkins console "Output: × 35 of 45 failed (78%) 06:13 247 3 38 66 140", I need to grep the number 78 and make the build failure if the number is >=30 with Groovy script.
Can someone please help me with this?

```
    def result= manager.logContains('%)')
    println result*.toString() // Read a line which has the failed test cases count
    String test = result
    def failedtest = test.substring(test.indexOf("%") - 2)
    def failednumber = failedtest.split("%")[0].toInteger() as int
    println failednumber
```

Comment: Do you need to know how to get a reference to that string in your Groovy code or do you already have that and just need the logic to find the `%` value inside the string?

Comment: I have this below code and it runs on eclipse but not on jenkins job:
              def result= manager.logContains('%)')
  println result*.toString() // Read a line which has the failed test cases count
  String test = result
  def failedtest = test.substring(test.indexOf("%") - 2)
  def failednumber = failedtest.split("%")[0].toInteger() as int
  println failednumber

Comment: You have `result*.toString()` which suggests that `result` is a collection.  You also have `String test = result ` which I think is going to invoke the `toString()` method on your collection and the result of that will be the value of `test`.  Is that your intent?